# Reading large csv files python and panda

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this Python server, that connecting to sftp server, and pulling CSV files (there is a For loop that running in a nodeJS server, each time a different connection is coming)
In that Python server - i'm reading the CSV file with panda - like this

```
        file = sftp.open(latestfile)
        check = pd.read_csv(file).to_csv()
```

at the end, i return the `check` with the CSV file data inisde - and than i parse in the nodeJS server.
this process went really good and i managed to achieve a lot of data this way - but my Python server really crashed when he tried to read a big CSV file (22MB)
i searched online and tried to solve it with chunks and with .modin library and dask.dataframe but everytime i tried to use one of thsee methods i couldn't read the file content properly (.to_csv part)
I'm really lost right now because i can't get it to work (there can be larger files than that)

Comment: To clarify, what do you mean by the server "really crashed" ? What happened ?

Comment: @ApplePie Both of the servers were running on an amazon instance, and now it is frozen and i can't access it,
In the logs i saw it stopped working since the python server fetched some CSV file
so i connected to that SFTP repository and downlaoded the file.
i ran that process locally and when the server tried to read that file i had this error -
[CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:11)
the amazon instance is still not responding.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to process your large csv files. It allows you to process groups of chunks at a time. You could modify it based on your requirements (such as through sftp etc).

**Minimal example**

```
import pandas as pd
chunksize = 10 ** 4
for chunk in pd.read_csv(latestfile, chunksize=chunksize):
    process(chunk.to_csv())
```

Comment: The problem is that i need to send the whole file content.
what am i doing with that process?

Comment: I can only return it when this chunk processing ends

Comment: one more thing - i get error of process is not defined (undefined variable)